# Nvidia Ion Asus Eee PC Seashell series 1215n and Optimus

Tags: nvidia-optimus, eeepc

I'm using ubuntu, lubuntu , kubuntu:

> Linux sysop 3.19.0-33-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:18:12 UTC
>   2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

on a Asus Eee PC Seashell series 1215n that has an Nvidia Ion card.
After installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime
```

lightdm gdm sddm fails to start.
If i want to get a graphical environment i have to:
log in in tty,
then do:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
startx
```

could someone help me make desktop manager work?

here the /var/log/Xorg.1.log file:

```
[    32.369] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.1
Release Date: 2015-02-10
[    32.369] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    32.369] Build Operating System: Linux 3.19.0-28-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    32.369] Current Operating System: Linux sysop 3.19.0-33-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:18:12 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    32.369] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic root=UUID=d414642e-6948-440a-a6cd-4fe8cc819dca ro
[    32.369] Build Date: 11 September 2015  10:30:58AM
[    32.370] xorg-server 2:1.17.1-0ubuntu3.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    32.370] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    32.370]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    32.370] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    32.370] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Sat Nov 14 09:17:13 2015
[    32.370] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    32.370] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    32.371] Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    Undefined Screen "nvidia" referenced by ServerLayout "layout".
[    32.371] (EE) Problem parsing the config file
[    32.371] (EE) Error parsing the config file
[    32.372] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    32.372] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    32.372] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    32.372] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[    32.372] (EE) 
[    32.372] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the several desktop managers working again:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  nvidia-346 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Check intel power saving mode.
Save and write/overwrite config.
Restart.
Lightdm is working now.
I think it was a problem with xorg configuration.
Althought my Question was only involving desktop managers like gdm lightdm, i think i haven't fixed any hardware acceleration.
But i got what i needed.
Hope this helps.